# MYSQL INTERVAL X MINUTEs with variable when passing from C

Tags: mysql, c

When I run my code to update an MYSQL record with this code, it works:

```
const char *update_query = "UPDATE `Time_Action_Settings` SET time= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) WHERE attribute='next_run'";
```

when I try to pass a variable in C using snprintf, the code runs I get an error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%d) MINUTE) WHERE attribute='next_run'' at line 1

```
const char *update_query = "UPDATE `Time_Action_Settings` SET time= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL %d MINUTE) WHERE attribute='next_run'";

if (mysql_query(conn, update_query) != 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit(1);

} else {

    if (snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), update_query, variable) >= sizeof(buffer))
    {
        printf("Issue with Buffer \n");
        exit (-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `snprintf()` first, and then use the buffer as the query that you pass to `mysql_query()`.

```
const char *update_query = "UPDATE `Time_Action_Settings` SET time= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL %d MINUTE) WHERE attribute='next_run'";
if (snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), update_query, variable) >= sizeof(buffer)) {
    printf("Issue with Buffer \n");
    exit (-1);
} else if (mysql_query(conn, buffer) != 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit(1);
}
```

You should also look into using [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-prepared-statement-function-overview.html) instead of substituting into the SQL string. This will protect against SQL-injection if you're substituting strings instead of numbers, and you don't have to worry about allocating a big enough buffer.